# ternary statement and do_shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, ternary

I am trying to get a wordpress theme to display the output from a plugin shortcode in a homepage featured area that currently seems to just pull text strings through from the options settings.
I have adapted the features.php file as follows:

```
<?php global $option_setting;
    $display_features = false;
    $meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'enable-features',true );
    if (isset($option_setting['features-enable']['enabled'])) :
    $enabled = $option_setting['features-enable']['enabled'];

if (((isset($enabled['blog']) ) && is_home() ) 
|| ((isset($enabled['staticpage'])) && is_front_page())
|| ((isset($enabled['posts'])) && is_single())
|| ((isset($enabled['archives'])) && is_archive())
|| ($meta)
|| ((isset($enabled['pages'])) && is_page()))
{
    $display_features = true;
}

if ($display_features) :
    if ( count($option_setting['features-main']) > 0 ) : ?>

    <div id="features-area">
    <div class="container">
        <?php
          $i = 0; foreach ( $option_setting['features-main'] as $features ) {
                    echo "<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-4 feature$i'><figure><div><a href='".esc_url($features['url'])."'><img src='".$features['image']."'><div class='features-caption'><div class='features-caption-title'>".$features['title']."</div>",($i==1 ? "<div class='features-caption-desc'><?php echo do_shortcode('[qemcalendar]'); ?></div></div></a></div></figure></div>" : "<div class='features-caption-desc'>".$features['description']."</div></div></a></div></figure></div>";
            $i++;   }
           ?>
     </div>   
    </div><!--.features-->
<?php endif;
endif;
endif; ?>
```

I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/pennybro/public_html/dev/wp-content/themes/pbcc/features.php on line 24
```

Line 24 is the echo and I imagine what I have done with the `<?php echo do_shortcode('[qemcalendar]'); ?>` is completely wrong, but am struggling to work out what I need to do instead.

I started out with an if else, but as this was inside the echo it wasn't very happy. I realise I may be trying to do something that simply won't work, but all thoughts appreciated!

Thanks,

Lisa

Comment: Wait, You never closed your ternary operation, did you?

Comment: Great spot! It doesn't error with the parenthesis in there, now I just need to work out why wordpress is ignoring the shortcode. A question for the theme designer I think. Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your text:

That's really long line is bad. Use this:

```
echo "<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-4 feature".$i."'>"
    . "<figure>"
    . "<div>"
    . "<a href='".esc_url($features['url'])."'>"
    . "<img src='".$features['image']."'>"
    . "<div class='features-caption'>"
    . "<div class='features-caption-title'>".$features['title']."</div>";
    if ($i==1) { echo "<div class='features-caption-desc'>" . do_shortcode('[qemcalendar]')
    . "</div>"
    . "</div>"
    . "</a>"
    . "</div>"
    . "</figure>"
    . "</div>";
    } else { 
        "<div class='features-caption-desc'>".$features['description']."</div></div></a></div></figure></div>";
    }
```

But I think, this is more readable:

```
<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-4 feature<?php echo $i; ?>'>
    <figure>
        <div>
            <a href='<?php echo esc_url($features['url']); ?>'>
                <img src='<?php echo $features['image']; ?>'>
                <div class='features-caption'>
                    <div class='features-caption-title'><?php echo $features['title']; ?></div>
                    <?php
                    if ($i == 1) {
                        ?>
                        <div class='features-caption-desc'><?php do_shortcode('[qemcalendar]'); ?></div>
                        <?php
                    } else {
                        ?>
                        <div class='features-caption-desc'><?php echo $features['description']; ?></div>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the first suggestion didn't error, but did do some very odd things to the layout (I'll check to see if there was a missing div close tag). The second suggestion resulted in this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/pennybro/public_html/dev/wp-content/themes/pbcc/features.php on line 24`

Comment: This code what I sent has no syntax error. Think about to use an IDE, to highlight the syntax error lines.

Comment: Must have been a knock on efect from combined php files in wordpress. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is a double echo.

You echo the ternary statement (because of the fact that you use a comma) but you echo this

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[qemcalendar]'); ?>
```

I think

```
. do_shortcode('[qemcalendar]') .
```

or to be consistent:

```
, do_shortcode('[qemcalendar]'),
```

will suffice.

Comment: Thanks, but I still get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/pennybro/public_html/dev/wp-content/themes/pbcc/features.php on line 24" as an error when using this suggestion.